# Make associative array into a collection similar to Eloquent query collection

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, collections

I have a class that is receiving API data and I would like to wrap all of the responses into a collection class. So, I receive the data from the API call, turn it into a plain associative php array, and wrap it using the `collect()` helper.

I was half expecting it to work just like Eloquent does where you can reference a key as a collection property, but it doesn't.

Here is an example of response data I would receive:

```
$data = [
    'status' => 'SUCCESS',
    'message' => 'Your request was received.',
    'data' => [
        'first_name' => 'John',
        'last_name' => 'Doe',
        'address' => [
            'street' => '123 Main St.',
            'city' => 'Any City',
            'state' => 'TX',
            'zip' => '12345',
            'country' => 'USA'
        ],
        'email' => 'john@doe.com',
        'phone' => '(123) 456-7890',
        'role' => 'Administrator',
        'active_orders' => 3
    ]
];

$response = collect($data);
```

I would like to be able to wrap this data in a collection and use it like so:

`$response->data->address->street` or `$response->data->first_name`

However, I get an error that says `Property [data] does not exist on this collection instance.` I have to refer to it like an array if I want to access it. E.g. `$response['data']['first_name']`. If I wanted to use that syntax I would just keep it as an array.

How can I recursively set my collection properties as the array key names so I can use it much like I would an Eloquent query?

Comment: How are you getting this response? If you are `json_decode`ing it as a result of an HTTP request, you can instead have `json_decode` return a `StdClass` object representation than an array. That would allow you to reference the data presented as you intend.

Answer (score 1):

> How can I recursively set my collection properties as the array key names so I can use it much like I would an Eloquent query?

`json_decode()` normally deconstructs into such an object. But you need to start with JSON. So, it seems silly, and it's probably not terribly efficient, but this should do what you want:

```
$response = json_decode(json_encode($data));
```

Comment: This is an effective way to convert an array to an object, but I would like to take advantage specifically of Laravel's collection class methods.

Comment: I think that you are mixin `Collections` and `Models` you can't use `->property` without use `->first()` before @Mark