# Laravel referencing string value instead of id

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, relational-database

Right now I'm grouping time entries by categories and months. The categories are stored in a separate table, and I'm referencing them on my main times' table with a foreign key constraint called category_id. I'm grouping the times by the category_id, but instead, I want to group them by the name of the category, so a string value.

**Should I just store the categorys in my main time table, by creating a column for categories?**

Currently, I have a 'times' table with:

```
        Schema::create('times', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('category_id');
            $table->date('start_day');
            $table->time('start_time');
            $table->time('finish_time');
            $table->time('duration');
            $table->text('notes');
            $table->timestamps();

            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
            $table->foreign('category_id')->references('id')->on('categories');
    }
```

and a categories table with:

```
       Schema::create('categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->string('type');
        });
    }
```

I'm grouping the times by the categories and months like the following:

```
 public function show(User $user) 
    {
        $data = collect(array_fill(1, 12, []))
            ->replace(
                $user->times()
                    ->whereYear('start_day', 2019)
                    ->groupBy('category_id', \DB::raw('month(start_day)'))
                    ->select([
                        'category_id',
                        \DB::raw('month(start_day) as month'),
                        \DB::raw('sum(duration) as duration'),
                    ])
                    ->orderBy(\DB::raw('month(start_day)'))
                    ->get()
                    ->mapToGroups(function ($item) {
                        return [$item['month'] => [
                            $item['category_id'] => $this->formatDuration($item['duration'])
                        ]];
                    })
                    ->mapWithKeys(function ($item, $key) {
                        return [$key => $item->collapse()];
                    })
            )
            ->mapToGroups(function ($item, $key) {
                $month = \DateTime::createFromFormat('!m', $key)->format('M');
                return [$month => $item];
            });

        return view('report.show', compact('data'));
    }
```

If I dd($data) this is output with an example of a 1-time entry for each category for November. I have 5 categories in total:

```
Collection {#327 ▼
  #items: array:12 [▼
    "Jan" => Collection {#315 ▶}
    "Feb" => Collection {#332 ▶}
    "Mar" => Collection {#335 ▶}
    "Apr" => Collection {#334 ▶}
    "May" => Collection {#333 ▶}
    "Jun" => Collection {#316 ▶}
    "Jul" => Collection {#320 ▶}
    "Aug" => Collection {#313 ▶}
    "Sep" => Collection {#318 ▶}
    "Oct" => Collection {#294 ▶}
    "Nov" => Collection {#321 ▼
      #items: array:1 [▼
        0 => Collection {#336 ▼
          #items: array:5 [▼
            0 => "12:00"
            1 => "11:00"
            2 => "12:00"
            3 => "12:00"
            4 => "12:00"
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
    "Dec" => Collection {#328 ▶}
  ]
```

Instead what I want the output to be:

```
"Nov" => Collection {#321 ▼
      #items: array:1 [▼
        0 => Collection {#336 ▼
          #items: array:5 [▼
            'Category Type 1' => "12:00"
            'Category Type 2' => "11:00"
            'Category Type 3' => "12:00"
            'Category Type 4' => "12:00"
            'Category Type 5' => "12:00"
          ]
        }
```

**Is there way to reference 'type' from the categories table, by using the category_id?**

Time Model:

```
class Time extends Model
{
    protected $guarded = [];

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }

    public function category()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Category');
    }


}
```

Category Model:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

class Category extends Model
{
    protected $guarded = [];

 public function time() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Time');
    }

}
```

User Model:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    public function times()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Time::class);
    }

    public function categories()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Category');
    }
}
```

Comment: For some reason, when I group them by ID, it's not grouping them correctly. When I group the ID, lets say I have one time entry from Category 2. The output will always start at 0

So it would be 
0 => "12:00" 

Instead of it being 2 => '12:00'  
Which I want it to be, because it's from category 2.

I was storing the categories in my times table before and was just grouping them like that and had no problem, but I figured it's probably more efficient to setup a separate table for categories.

Comment: hm... you try to use collection as associative array, is it possible? probably you need another approach, see also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46221804/make-associative-array-into-a-collection-similar-to-eloquent-query-collection)

Comment: Do you have a relationship set up for category and time?

Comment: I updated my OP with my models. I'm not sure if there correct, i'm fairly new to laravel. However the way my application works is: A user can make as many time entries as he wants, but each time entry belongs to one category. You can  have multiple time entries, with all them belonging to the same category.

Comment: cheers mate. I think i helped you on a question you had posted on this app before. Check out my profile and shoot me an email. i'll be happy to help you get this project figured out if it's giving you so much trouble

Comment: Yea, now that I think of it, your name does look familiar lol. Will do, appreciate the help :)